# How to design a state variable and increment based on special conditions?

Tags: go

Here is my program structure

```
type myType struct {
   Attr map[string]any
   // some other variables
}
func (t *Tran) foo () {
  // some logic
  count := 0
  for i, v := range myArray {
    count = t.boo(i, v, count)
  }  
}

func (t *Tran) boo (i int, v string, count int) int {
  // bunch of logic
  e := myType{}
  if v == "special" {
    e.Attr = map[string]any{"num": count}
    count += 1
  else {
    e.Attr = map[string]any{}
  }
  t.state[i] = e
  return count
}
```

Notice the count variable increments based on the "special" string. The program works fine. But I feel there might be smarter way to implement this count state variable. Also Foo can be called many times.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you post a playground link or complete code without assumptions on what `myType{}` is?

Comment: The "e" variable is allocated and then thrown away?

Comment: @marco.m added more logic

Comment: @Inian added myType, you can fill in other parts to make it compile but the idea is there. let me know anything else is missing.

Comment: What is `Tran` ?It is not a good idea to leave assumptions to make. If you can take an extra minute to post a complete verifiable example, if will be easy for folks looking at in the future

Comment: Tran is a struct. you can store variables within it if you think that is a proper solution. i dont have constraint to modify Tran

Comment: I suggest to write a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then people trying to help you will have enough context. As-is, we are going in circles with questions, it seems a detective game :-)